# TxnMode error for Paysafe API

Tags: netbanx-api, paysafe

I have been trying to get a sample Web Services request to go through and I keep receiving an error. See my Setup.

Account Number: 89994061
Store ID: test
Store Password: test

Sample Request (Code)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<title>Credit Card Test</title>
<body>
<form NAME="Credit Card" METHOD="post"
ACTION="https://webservices.optimalpayments.com/creditcardWS/CreditCardServlet/v1">
<input type=hidden name="txnmode" value="ccAuthorize" >
<b>XML Message body:</b>
<TEXTAREA class="xmlbox" name="txnRequest" COLS=100 ROWS=10 >
<ccAuthRequestV1 xmlns="http://www.optimalpayments.com/creditcard/xmlschema/v1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.optimalpayments.com/creditcard/xmlschema/v1">
<merchantAccount>
<accountNum>89994061</accountNum>
<storeID>test</storeID>
<storePwd>test</storePwd>
</merchantAccount>
<merchantRefNum>Ref-12345</merchantRefNum>
<amount>10.00</amount>
<card>
<cardNum>4XXXXXXXXXXXXXX1</cardNum>
<cardExpiry>
<month>11</month>
<year>2015</year>
</cardExpiry>
<cardType>VI</cardType>
<cvdIndicator>1</cvdIndicator>
<cvd>111</cvd>
</card>
<authentication>
<indicator>05</indicator>
<cavv>AAABB4WZlQAAAAAAcJmVENiWiV+=</cavv>
<xid>Q2prWUI2RFNBc3FOTXNlem50eWY=</xid>
</authentication>
<billingDetails>
<cardPayMethod>WEB</cardPayMethod>
<firstName>Jane</firstName>
<lastName>Jones</lastName>
<street>123 Main Street</street>
<city>LA</city>
<state>CA</state>
<country>US</country>
<zip>90210</zip>
<phone>555-555-5555</phone>
<email>janejones@emailserver.com</email>
</billingDetails>
<shippingDetails>
<carrier>FEX</carrier>
<shipMethod>T</shipMethod>
<firstName>Jane</firstName>
<lastName>Jones</lastName>
<street>44 Main Street</street>
<city>LA</city>
<state>CA</state>
<country>US</country>
<zip>90210</zip>
<phone>555-555-5555</phone>
<email>janejones@emailserver.com</email>
</shippingDetails>
<recurring>
<recurringIndicator>I</recurringIndicator>
<originalConfirmationNumber>115147689</originalConfirmationNumber>
</recurring>
<customerIP>127.0.0.1</customerIP>
<productType>M</productType>
<addendumData>
<tag>CUST_ACCT_OPEN_DATE</tag>
<value>20041012</value>
</addendumData>
<addendumData>
<tag>MERCHANT_COUNTRY_CODE</tag>
<value>US</value>
</addendumData>
<addendumData>
<tag>SERVICE_REQUEST_CURRENCY</tag>
<value>on</value>
</addendumData>
</ccAuthRequestV1>
</TEXTAREA>
<br>
<input TYPE=submit class=input VALUE="Send Request">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error Received

Required String parameter 'txnMode' is not present

This is the exact request from the documentation and it is not working for me. What am I doing that is incorrect? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it would look like everything is good. However there is one slight mistake in the code. You have the following line in the HTML POST

```
<input type=hidden name="txnmode" value="ccAuthorize" >
```

The correct way of doing it is the following

```
<input type=hidden name="txnMode" value="ccAuthorize" >
```

The issue is that the actual txnMode name is spelled incorrectly. This is case sensitive. Once you make this change you should receive a proper response from the Web Services API.